# Cannot build clean VSIX project: Tries to load Newtonsoft.Json which is not there?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

The following build error is pestering me.

```
The "CompareCommonBuildTaskVersion" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\Thijs\.nuget\packages\microsoft.vssdk.buildtools\16.6.1026\tools\VSSDK\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Sdk.BuildTasks.dll. 
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

I just checked the directory mentioned, and there is a Newtonsoft.Json.dll there, but it's version 12.0.2.23222 (File Version).

I'm using:

- Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Preview

  - Version 16.6.0 Preview 1.0
- Visual Studio Enterprise 2019

  - Version 16.5.0

Upon reading the link EricEJ posted I checked my devenv.exe.config which has the following (correct) AssemblyRedirect:

```
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.5.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.2"/>
      <codeBase version="12.0.0.2" href="PrivateAssemblies\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.0.2\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
```

Problem seems to be with the actual BuildTools package (see answer).

Comment: Did you read this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/using-newtonsoft-json-in-a-visual-studio-extension/

Comment: @ErikEJ That is enlightening, I didn't read that before. It does talk about "when you want to use Newtonsoft.Json" which is not something I want.

From what I understand now is that probably the devenv.exe.config binding redirect is wrong *somehow*. I'll check that.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I was waiting for someone (could be me) to also be able to explain the "why". Since the ROI on that is pretty low I'll accept my current answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the different BuildTools package versions again, starting from the newest and after installing, restarted VS and then did a rebuild of the solution:

- Version 16.6.1026 -> March -> Not working
- Version 16.6.1024 -> March -> Not working
- Version 16.5.2044 - February -> Working

So far it seems the downgrade has resolved my issues.

Comment: When you create a project in VS 2019 16.6 preview 1 it adds the BuildTools package with version 16.6.3 (which is not on NuGet.org). I am using that version now.